# Performance | Binary vs script

Tags: linux, scripting, compiling, performance

If I want to implement some functionalities in Linux (e.g. open, copy, compress, delete, waiting events), is it better to implement it in C++ and run the binary as a process or to implement it in a shell script?

Assuming I ignore the details of the implementation, I would like to now, during the start of the binary as a process, how many memory and cpu load will be consumed compared to start the shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will in make a difference in speed? Yes an No

If you are implementing a compression algorithm in a script, then it will be much slower than what can be done in C++.

If you are just calling a library-function / command to do it, then there will be little difference. The time will be dominated by the compression done by the pre-existing library-function / command. File-open, file-copy, file-delete, and wait are done by the kernel, very little is done in the application, so again little change.

However the only ways to know, is to measure both.

## Some rules of optimisation

- Get it to work, then (if necessary) make it fast/small.
- Optimise for readability.
- Optimise for speed, only after you have evidence that it is not fast **enough**.
- When optimising for speed, measure both implementations, don't assume that one is faster (you will probably be wrong).
- Never optimise for the best case, optimise for worse or average case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I don't want to implement the compression algorithm in a script. In my opinion, the C++ binary has to be always faster if the code implements the direct syscall instead of calling the Linux command using `popen` or `system()`.

Comment: Yes that is my point. As a side note there is no syscall for compression. It will just be some user-land code running an algorithm.